# VS-Code Flutter debug doesn't work if I don't compile with Xcode directly before

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

For some reason, running my Flutter app via VS-Code doesn't work anymore, unless I compile the App via Xcode directly before it. I get this error:

**Error**

```
Could not obtain access to one or more requested file system resources because
CoreDevice was unable to create bookmark data.
```

**Details**

```
Could not obtain access to one or more requested file system resources because CoreDevice was unable to create bookmark data.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 1005
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-09-22 19:02:54 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    NSURL = "file:///Users/anon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-abohmwqifnxvoqgcnhfjfotgyrud/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app";
}
--
The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 260
Failure Reason: The file doesn’t exist.
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone15,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.0.1 (21A340)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.2.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 3;
    "operation_errorCode" = 260;
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError.1005.NSCocoaErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 8192;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.0 (Build 23A339)
Xcode 15.0 (22265) (Build 15A240d)
Timestamp: 2023-09-22T21:02:54+02:00
```

This happens every time if I didn't compile the app with Xcode before it. For example if compile the App with Xcode, I can run it via VS-Code, but if I terminate the App and try to launch it via Xcode again, I get this error again, and compiling with Xcode again fixes it.

I have the newest version of Flutter, reinstalled Xcode (+ Deleted every associated file) and the Flutter extension, and no custom run config and I didn't modify the settings for the Flutter extension.

What could be causing this?

Comment: by newest version, what version did you mean ? I am seeing that latest 3.13.5 has some fixes for macos

Comment: @solsTiCe yes, I have 3.13.5

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Flutter from version 3.13.5 to 3.13.7 fixed the problem for me.